# VB.Net Parameter count mismatch

Tags: vb.net

I'm writing a function that convert an Array List into a Data Table, and I'm getting an error "Parameter count mismatch".

I've been looking and googling the issue but couldn't found anything that could help me resolve my issue.

````
```
   'Function that convert ArrayList to DataTable
Public Function ConvertArrayListToDataTable(ByVal MyAList As ArrayList) As DataTable

    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    For i As Integer = 0 To MyAList.Count - 1

        'create a Generic Object
        Dim values As Object = MyAList.Item(i)
        Dim properties() As PropertyInfo =  
   values.GetType().GetProperties()


    'Loop through each property, and add it as a column to the datatable

        For Each prop As PropertyInfo In properties
            Try
                Dim dc As DataColumn = New DataColumn(prop.Name)

                'Add the column definition to the datatable
                dc.DataType = prop.PropertyType
                dt.Columns.Add(dc)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(" Can't add column" & ex.Message)
            End Try

        Next

        'for each object in the list, loop through and add
        'the data to the database
        For Each o As Object In MyAList
            Try
                'create new row
                Dim row As DataRow = dt.NewRow()
                Dim pf() As PropertyInfo = o.GetType().GetProperties()

                For Each item As PropertyInfo In pf
                    row(item.Name) = item.GetValue(o, Nothing)
                Next

                dt.Rows.Add(row)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(" Conversionerror" & ex.Message)
            End Try
        Next
    Next
    Return dt
End Function
```
````

I see the code get the Table and the column count as well, but cannot write value. it failed on getvalue.
The function suppose return a datatable containing retrieved data and populate datagrid

```
For Each prop As PropertyInfo In properties
            Try
                Dim dc As DataColumn = New DataColumn(prop.Name)
                dc.DataType = prop.PropertyType
                dt.Columns.Add(dc)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MessageBox.Show(" Can't add column" & ex.Message)
            End Try

Next
```

Comment: Where is your data coming from? I think you might be re-inventing the wheel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are filling a DataTable from a database just let the DataTable figure out the datatype. ArrayList is not used in new code. You can make a class or structure and then use List(Of T) or if absolutely necessary List(Of Object). Test just the plain old DataTable.

```
Private Sub FillDataGridView()
    Dim dt = New DataTable()
    Using cn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.CoffeeConnection)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("Select * From Coffees;", cn)
            cn.Open()
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
        Debug.Print(col.DataType.Name)
    Next
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Mary. It was a great experience. I was challenging myself to see how I can fill the Datagrid from Arraylist to Datatable. I finally follow your advice and review my Function as below:

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Mary. It was a great experience. I was challenging myself to see how I can fill the Datagrid from Arraylist to Datatable. I finally follow your advice and review my Function as below:

```
      Public Function FillDataGridView(SQLStatement As String) As DataTable
        'create an DataTable to hold the results
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        Try
            Using con As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
                con.Open()
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand(SQLStatement, con)
                    'Get the reader
                    Using Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
                        dt.Load(Reader)
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
            For Each col As DataColumn In dt.Columns
                Debug.Print(col.DataType.Name)
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("SQL retrieve row:" & ex.Message & Err.Number)
        Finally
            Call CloseConn()
        End Try
        Return dt
    End Function
```

Comment: Terrific! You don't need to call `CloseConn()` The connection is closed and disposed with the `End Using`. `con` is created locally in the Function and killed off in the same Function.

Comment: Yes Mary, I commented that in my last code. Thank you a lot